# Why is the use-Tag from SVG in ImageMagick ignored?

Tags: svg, imagemagick

If you e.g. **use** (no pun intended) the example usage of the **use** tag for SVG from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue" />
  <use href="#myCircle" x="10" fill="blue" />
  <use href="#myCircle" x="20" fill="white" stroke="red" />
</svg>
```

and watch it in your browser you will see three circles, the original and two re**use**d copies. If you on the other hand feed this code to ImageMagick you will only see one circle as the **use** tag is ignored by the SVG processor in ImageMagick.
Is there any way to repair this?

- Image as it should be: [image: Three circles in a horizontal row]
- as displayed by ImageMagick: [image: One circle]

Comment: Does it need xlink:href instead?

Comment: ... and add the xlink namespace attribute `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` to your svg.

Comment: If both of you would have proposed that solution I'd choose it as the correct one!

Answer (score 3):

**ImageMagick** uses its own internal SVG reader if you do not configure and build it with a high quality SVG converter, such as `rsvg`. If you use `rsvg`, it renders your SVG perfectly.

Obviously you don't have `rsvg` support, but in general you can tell if you have `rsvg` support with:

```
magick identify -version

Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-26 Q16-HDRI aarch64 21914 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jpeg jxl lcms ltdl lzma pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib zstd
```

and look through the list of delegates, which is in alphabetical order, and see if `rsvg` appears.

If you don't have it, either build a version with it by installing `rsvg` support with your OS's package manager, then installing **ImageMagick** from source, remembering to use the following at the configuring stage:

```
./configure --with-rsvg ...
```

or, more simply, use the `alpine:latest` docker image:

```
docker run -it alpine:latest
apk update && apk add imagemagick rsvg-convert
```

---

Or, as Fred suggests in the comments, you can just install Inkscape.

Comment: Or just install Inkscape. That works fine, too.  It is easier to just install Inkscape that install a new delegate and recompile Imagemagick.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks Fred, I have added your idea into the answer where it is more prominent and easier for folks to find.

Answer (score 0):

As you see ImageMagick is ignoring the  tag, so the elements are not being replicated as you would like it.

to achive what you would like, you have to pre-process the SVG before submitting it.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 30 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle id="myCircle1" cx="5" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue" fill="blue" />

  <circle id="myCircle2" cx="15" cy="5" r="4" stroke="blue" fill="white" />

  <circle id="myCircle3" cx="25" cy="5" r="4" stroke="red" fill="white" />

</svg>
```

After that, rasterize the new SVG.

```
convert input.svg output.png
```

That should work.